# Pyzmq - send message to STREAM socket

Tags: python, pyzmq

I am trying to implement simple example of connection between two STREAM sockets in pyzmq.

**sender.py**

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")
socket.send("message")
```

**receiver.py**

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

message = socket.recv()
print("Received -> [ %s ]" % (message))
```

**Output**

```
Received [ b'\x00k\x8bEg' ]
Received [ b'' ]
```

I would like to ask what is the correct way to send message between STREAM sockets.

Comment: Zdravím do Bľavy. Pomohla navigace v odpovědi? StackOverflow říká uživatelům, že dobré otázky i dobré odpovědi si zaslouží feedback a hlas a nejlepší pak [Accept]. Tak napiš a zaklikej :o)

Comment: Dakujem za odpoved. Nemal som este bohuzial cas sa k nej vyjadrit ale zodpovedala moju otazku. Skoda ze nie aj moju dilemu :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **`socket.recv()`**-ed data are exactly matching the ZeroMQ specification, though they need not have made you happy and you doubt why you did get this, instead of nicely delivered exact copies of messages sent.

So, be patient and keep reading.

### ZeroMQ recently added `STREAM` socket-archetype is rather specific

Anyone having a few years experience with ZeroMQ signalling/messaging tools will tell you that the recently ( v4.x ) added `STREAM` archetype is not the best choice for a ZeroMQ-process to a ZeroMQ-process intercommunication needs.

Why? Allmost all the gems, that the ZeroMQ tools have are and must be shortcut in `STREAM`, so as to allow a ZeroMQ socket access-point become able to "speak" to an opposite socket endpoint process, which knows nothing about ZeroMQ smart-sockets higher-level protocols.

> **Native pattern**
>
> The native pattern is used for communicating with TCP peers and allows asynchronous requests and replies in either direction.
>   **`ZMQ_STREAM`**
>
> A socket of type `ZMQ_STREAM` is used to send and receive TCP data from a non-ØMQ peer, when using the **`tcp://`** transport. A `ZMQ_STREAM` socket can act as client and/or server, sending and/or receiving TCP data asynchronously.
>
> When receiving TCP data, a `ZMQ_STREAM` socket shall prepend a message part containing the identity of the originating peer to the message before passing it to the application. Messages received are fair-queued from among all connected peers.
>
> When sending TCP data, a `ZMQ_STREAM` socket shall remove the first part of the message and use it to determine the identity of the peer the message shall be routed to, and unroutable messages shall cause an `EHOSTUNREACH` or `EAGAIN` error.
>
> To open a connection to a server, use the **`zmq_connect()`** call, and then fetch the socket identity using the `ZMQ_IDENTITY` **`zmq_getsockopt()`** call.
>
> To close a specific connection, send the identity frame followed by a zero-length message (see EXAMPLE section).
>
> When a connection is made, a zero-length message will be received by the application. Similarly, when the peer disconnects (or the connection is lost), a zero-length message will be received by the application.
>
> You must send one identity frame followed by one data frame. The `ZMQ_SNDMORE` flag is required for identity frames but is ignored on data frames.
>
> ### EXAMPLE

```
void    *ctx = zmq_ctx_new ();
assert ( ctx );
/*                                             Create ZMQ_STREAM socket */
void    *socket = zmq_socket ( ctx, ZMQ_STREAM );
assert ( socket );

int      rc = zmq_bind ( socket, "tcp://*:8080" );
assert ( rc == 0 );

/*                                            Data structure to hold the ZMQ_STREAM ID */
uint8_t id [256];
size_t  id_size = 256;

/*                                            Data structure to hold the ZMQ_STREAM received data */
uint8_t raw [256];
size_t  raw_size = 256;

while ( 1 ) {
   /*                                         Get HTTP request; ID frame and then request */
   id_size  = zmq_recv ( socket, id, 256, 0 );
   assert ( id_size >  0 );
   do {
        raw_size  = zmq_recv ( socket, raw, 256, 0 );
        assert ( raw_size >= 0 );
   } while (     raw_size == 256 );
   /*                                         Prepares the response */
   char http_response [] =
                            "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                            "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
                            "\r\n"
                            "Hello, World!";
   /*                                         Sends the ID frame followed by the response */
   zmq_send ( socket, id, id_size, ZMQ_SNDMORE );
   zmq_send ( socket, http_response, strlen ( http_response ), 0 );

   /*                                         Closes the connection by sending the ID frame followed by a zero response */
   zmq_send ( socket, id, id_size, ZMQ_SNDMORE );
   zmq_send ( socket, 0, 0, 0 );
}
zmq_close ( socket );
zmq_ctx_destroy ( ctx );
```

---

If you follow the description of the `STREAM` behaviour on the multi-connected socket cases, the sender side will happen to receive a fair-queue round-robin reads on the **`socket`** instance, which is connected ( 1x via the `.connect()` + Nx via `.bind()`, `N = < 0, +INF )` ) to multiple endpoints, so far with zero control of either the count or/and the nature of the communicating peers, yet having a fair-queued round-robin mechanism on the `socket.recv()`-s. Definitely not a safe design practice.

```
Summary of ZMQ_STREAM characteristics
Compatible peer sockets     none
Direction                   Bidirectional
Send/receive pattern        Unrestricted
Outgoing routing strategy   See text ( above )
Incoming routing strategy   Fair-queued
Action in mute state        EAGAIN
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplified example using pyzmq with one way connection as in the question.

**sender.py**

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)

socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')
id_sock = socket.getsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY)
socket.send(id_sock, zmq.SNDMORE)
socket.send(b'message')
```

**receiver.py**

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.STREAM)

socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
id_sock = socket.recv()
assert not socket.recv()    # empty data here
assert socket.recv() == id_sock
message = socket.recv()
print('received:', message)
```